# Question on Rudin's Principles of Math. Analysis theorem 9.12

Tags: real-analysis

**9.11 Definition** Suppose  is an open set in $^{n}$, f maps  into $^{m}$, and $x ∈$. If there exists a linear transformation  of $^{n}$ into $^{m}$ such that
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left|\mathbf{f(x +h)-f(x)-Ah}\right|}{|\mathbf{h}|}=0,\tag{14}$$

**9.12 Theorem** Suppose  and **f** are as in Definition 9.11, $x ∈$, and (14) holds with =1 and with =2. Then 1=2.

Here's Rudin's Proof

> If $\mathbf{B=A_1-A_2}$, the inequality$$\left|\mathbf{Bh}\right|\le\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h}\right|+\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_2h}\right|$$
> shows that$\frac{|\mathbf{Bh}|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. For fixed $\mathbf{h\ne 0}$, it follows that
> $$\frac{|\mathbf{B(th)}|}{|\mathbf{th}|}\to 0 \text{ as } t\to 0.\tag{16}$$
> The linearity of  shows that the left side of (16) is independent of $t$. Thus $=0$ for every $∈R^{n}$. Hence $=0$.

I don't understand from where does this line comes  : $$\left|\mathbf{Bh}\right|\le\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h}\right|+\left|\mathbf{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_2h}\right|$$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

He uses the triangle inequality as follows:

$\lvert Bh \rvert = \lvert A_1 h - A_2 h \rvert = \lvert -(f(x +h) - f(x) - A_1h) + (f(x+h) - f(x) - A_2h)\rvert \leq \lvert -(f(x +h) - f(x) - A_1h)\vert + \lvert f(x+h) - f(x) - A_2 h\rvert \; ,$

and the signal in the first summand is is cancelled because $\lvert -x \rvert = \lvert x \rvert$.